# How to check existence of a folder with python and then remove it?

Tags: python, linux, rmdir

I want to remove dataset folder from dataset3 folder. But the following code is not removing dataset. 
First I want to check if dataset already exist in dataset then remove dataset. 
Can some one please point out my mistake in following code?

```
for files in os.listdir("dataset3"):
    if os.path.exists("dataset"):
        os.system("rm -rf "+"dataset")
```

Comment: @HFBrowning - that's not too effective against directories.

Comment: You don't use the `files` filename and even if you did, you need to add the original path ('dataset3') to it.

Comment: Then how I can do that

Comment: By dataset folder, its literally named "dataset"?

Comment: If you know the name of the directory, there is no need for any checks. `os.system("rm -rf dataset3/dataset")` does the job.

Comment: you are looping over all files under "dataset3" and for each file in "dataset3" you are deleting "dataset" - "dataset" has to be on the same directory-level as "dataset3"!?   Does this make sense?

Comment: In my actual code  when i run my programe it generates a dataset folder. I shif it in dataset3 folder.But when next time I run the same programe using same parameter I'm unable to move dataset into dataset3 because it already exists there. That's why I want to check its existance that if it already exists then remove it so that I can shift a new dataset into dataset3

Answer (score 132):

Python's [`os.rmdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir) only works on empty the directories, however [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) doesn't care (even if there are subdirectories) which makes it very similar to the Linux `rm -rf` command.

```
import os
import shutil

dirpath = os.path.join('dataset3', 'dataset')
if os.path.exists(dirpath) and os.path.isdir(dirpath):
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

**Modern approach**

In Python 3.4+ you can do same thing using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module to make the code more object-oriented and readable:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

dirpath = Path('dataset3') / 'dataset'
if dirpath.exists() and dirpath.is_dir():
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

Comment: Is `Path` a relative path? I prefer absolute paths as is common sense.

Comment: @Timo: In this case its value happens to be relative. A [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) is a subclass of the `PurePath` class that's defined in the `pathlib` module and are not absolute nor relative per se — they can be either. These classes make accessing components of path easy to access and allows operations on them to be done in an object-oriented fashion. Also note that sometime using a relative path makes perfect sense — such as when you don't want to hardcode an absolute path into your code or won't know what the root folder is until runtime.

Comment: in both ancient and modern code snippets, isn't `exists() and is_dir()` the same as just `is_dir()` ?

Answer (score 26):

`os.remove()` is to remove a file.

`os.rmdir()` is to remove an empty directory.

`shutil.rmtree()` is to delete a directory and all its contents.

```
import os

folder = "dataset3/"

# Method 1
for files in os.listdir(folder):
    if files == "dataset":
        os.remove(folder + "dataset")

# Method 2
if os.path.exists(folder + "dataset"):
    os.remove(folder + "dataset")
```

Answer (score 26):

Better to set `ignore_errors`:

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('/folder_name', ignore_errors=True)
```

This is much more readable, and concise.

Note that it will ignore **all** errors, not just dir missing errors.

Comment: Yeah, so better not to do this, really :) - Otherwise you won't know if it failed to clear the folder.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for files in os.listdir("dataset3"):
  if files=="dataset":
    fn=os.path.join("dataset3", files)
    os.system("rm -rf "+fn)
    break
```

You do not need the os.path.exists() because os.listdir() already told you, that it exists.

And if your foldernames are static, you can do it with:

```
if os.path.exists("dataset3/dataset"):
  os.system("rm -rf dataset3/dataset")
```

or as:

```
try:
  os.system("rm -rf dataset3/dataset")
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
for files in os.listdir('dataset3'):
     if files == 'dataset':
         os.rmdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + 'dataset3', files))
```

Comment: For `os.path.join()`, you don't need/want to include the leading slash in the `'/dataset3'`.

Comment: @martineau fixed!